In Matthew 19:17, Mark 10:18, and Luke 18:19, why does Jesus say that he and everyone else is not good except God only if he himself is also God?
Matthew 19:17 ESV

And he said to him, “Why do you ask me about what is good? There is
only One who is good. If you would enter life, keep the commandments.”

Mark 10:18 ESV

And Jesus said to him, “Why do you call me good? No one is good except
God alone.

Luke 18:19 ESV

And Jesus said to him, “Why do you call me good? No one is good except
God alone.

If Jesus says that he is not good, but that only God is good in the third person, doesn't that mean that Jesus is not God and that only his Father is God?

but Jesus doesn't say that he's not good - that's to draw a converse

Voted to close for lack of clarity. Is it not clear that Jesus does not say that he is not good ?

. . . . and, here again also, this question is answered many times, such as  Why do you call me good ?.

It looks like your problem is denial. If the man believes Jesus is good, then he should address Him accordingly.

@FelixLXX - Yes, Jesus is perfectly good, but that is only because the source of all that is good, the Spirit of God his Father, dwells within him as it does in us!

No need to close.  His question is similar but different and easily answered thus clear.  See my answer.

@JoshuaB but again, you have let your contention remain that Jesus says something that he does not say. The converse you draw is no more present in the text than, and has no privilege over, this other: that Jesus' interlocutor might have said "I call you good because you are God" and that Jesus' question was in case he was overheard by pharisaic types who used the shema as an excuse to believe themselves full of God

@FelixLXX - That was not said. Jesus responded to his interlocutor by reminding him that nobody is good unless the Spirit of the Most High is within them, and that includes Jesus who is God's Son! That is reason why he said only God is good!

Jesus says, “No one is good except God alone.” Jesus does not say that he himself is not good. In fact, he claims that he needs to be followed for the man to be perfect.
We see that Jesus is making a distinction between human goodness and divine goodness.
Logical Analysis:

If Jesus is not good, and only God is good, then Jesus is not God.
If Jesus is good, and only God is good, then Jesus must be God.

Jesus makes this profound statement. What we learn from it is that true goodness is a divine attribute. So, if the young man believes Jesus is truly good, he should logically conclude that Jesus is divine.
However, the man was proud.

He thought he had perfectly obeyed the law. He said he has obeyed it
from his youth.
This, of course, is completely impossible, as Jesus knew. Yet rather
than challenge the young man on his perceived moral perfection, Jesus
“upped the ante” on the man as a way to show the man that he was not
as righteous as he thought.
Jesus told the man to do something which the man could not do. He
should sell all his riches and give the money to the poor. Yet even
this was not the end, for after he did this, Jesus told the man to
“Come, follow Me” (Matthew 19:21; Mark 10:21; Luke 18:22). [1]


Jesus said to him, “If you want to be perfect, go, sell what you have
and give to the poor, and you will have treasure in heaven; and come,
follow Me.” (Matthew 19:21)

By stating that following Him is necessary for perfection, Jesus is implying that He is the way to divine perfection.
The statement implies that Jesus has a divine nature because He is the one who can lead people to perfection, a state associated only with God.

Jason, your logic is a disaster. If Jesus is God because Jesus is good, then are we also God if we are good? Of course not. Jesus was teaching us that all goodness comes from God, and God alone is good, because God is the eternal source of what is good. Jesus is good only because God is good; the good Spirit of God dwells within him as it also dwells within us and makes Christ and us good just as God is good.

@JoshuaB "Good" here is being used in the sense of perfectly good. I thought that was clear by the context. That's why I stated that there is a distinction between human goodness and divine goodness.

Jason, there is no distinction in goodness. All goodness is good, and all of it comes from God alone by softening hearts.

@JoshuaB With due respect there is still a distinction. The distinction, then, is not in the quality of goodness but in its source: for humans, goodness is received; for God, it is an essential attribute. While I understand that we have different perspectives on this matter, and I'm unable to align with your viewpoint, I appreciate the dialogue. I do believe that it's important to have these conversations. They help us to challenge our own beliefs and grow. Let’s continue to share and learn. I just ask that there is mutual respect as the foundation of further dialogue.

Jesus did not say he was not good.  It is as if Jesus said, "Only God is good.  Are you calling me God."

And behold, a man came up to him, saying, “Teacher, what good deed must I do to have eternal life?”  And he said to him, “Why do you ask me about what is good? There is only one who is good. If you would enter life, keep the commandments.”
(Matt.  19:16–17, ESV)

What did Jesus say about himself?

I am the good shepherd. The good shepherd lays down his life for the sheep.
(John 10:11, ESV)


"I and the Father are one.”  The Jews picked up stones again to stone him.  Jesus answered them, “I have shown you many good works from the Father; for which of them are you going to stone me?”  The Jews answered him, “It is not for a good work that we are going to stone you but for blasphemy, because you, being a man, make yourself God.”
(John 10:30–33, ESV)


If I am not doing the works of my Father, then do not believe me; but if I do them, even though you do not believe me, believe the works, that you may know and understand that the Father is in me and I am in the Father.”  Again they sought to arrest him, but he escaped from their hands.
(John 10:37–39)


Or is Jesus only good because the eternal God alone is the only source of all that is good, including Jesus' goodness?

@ Joshua  But I was answering your question, "Why did Jesus say he was not good?"

Jesus is only good because the Spirit of the good eternal God is within him completely.

To demonstrate an attitude of humility. By way of example, Plato in The Republic discusses via Socrates that a truly good person must be good in truth, but not appear good. To proclaim your own goodness is to seek praise. It’s boastful and proud. The truly good don’t seek the gratification of their own egos and self-affirmation. Someone who is truly good will be hated and reviled, and ultimately murdered, as Christ actually was. Paul, in fact, appears to be directly referencing Plato in one passage.

Or is Jesus simply meaning that God is the only source of all that is good, as He is the eternal Light.

The context of the Luke and Mark verses the OP quoted are the same, so we can look at either account. Let’s look at Mark 10:17-22 (CSB):

17 As he was setting out on a journey, a man ran up, knelt down
before him, and asked him, “Good teacher, what must I do to inherit
eternal life?”
18 “Why do you call me good?” Jesus asked him. “No one is good except
God alone.
19 You know the commandments: Do not murder; do not commit adultery;
do not steal; do not bear false witness; do not defraud; honor your
father and mother.”
20 He said to him, “Teacher, I have kept all these from my youth.”
21 Looking at him, Jesus loved him and said to him, “You lack one
thing: Go, sell all you have and give to the poor, and you will have
treasure in heaven. Then come, follow me.”
22 But he was dismayed by this demand, and he went away grieving,
because he had many possessions.

There are a couple of things happening here. First, the young man addresses Jesus as “good teacher” (vs 17):
The young man’s question presumes that Jesus knows the specific things that can be done to achieve “goodness” and therefore attain eternal life.
Jesus corrects his thinking, advising him that goodness cannot be attained by following the law (vs 19). God alone is the source of all goodness (vs 18).
This is not a contradiction to Jesus’ divinity, but a loving (vs 21) correction of the young man’s mistaken assumptions about his ability to earn eternity and of Jesus’ identity as merely a teacher.
If He indeed was just a teacher, He could not also be good, as God alone is good, and goodness cannot be attained through works of the law (merely doing all the things God instructed).
He sees through to the man’s heart (vs 21-22) and tells the young ruler that it’s his heart that needs to change (vs 21), and that is the purpose behind the laws, as Jesus consistently teaches:
Matthew 5:21-22 (CSB)

“You have heard that it was said to our ancestors, Do not murder, and
whoever murders will be subject to judgment. But I tell you, everyone
who is angry with his brother or sister will be subject to judgment.
Whoever insults his brother or sister, will be subject to the court.
Whoever says, ‘You fool!’ will be subject to hellfire.”

Matthew 5:27-28 (CSB)

“You have heard that it was said, Do not commit adultery. But I tell
you, everyone who looks at a woman lustfully has already committed
adultery with her in his heart.”

See Matthew 5-7 for more of Jesus teachings in this regard.
So to summarize, Jesus, as the fulfillment of the law (Matthew 5:17), instructs the young man that following the law is insufficient. Instead, he is to give up such worldly notions and follow Jesus (vs 21).

Don, the point Jesus was making is that the only reason why he or any of us is good is if the Spirit of the eternal God his Father is working within us. That is what made Jesus a good teacher: the Spirit of his God, the Father, was working all the good in him. This amazes me.

@joshuab I agree it’s amazing. Jesus is certainly indirectly claiming to be good as he declares God to be good. We, as the readers understand this to be true. In this passage, however He does not claim to be a good teacher nor does he claim to be God. He instead asks a question “why do you call me good?”, which fits into his practice of avoiding claims of divinity as His time had not yet come. John 2:4, John 7:6, John 7:30, John 8:20

Don - No man has ever seen God (John 1:18), yet people saw Jesus, because he is not God, but God's Son! Paul said in 1 Corinthians 8:6 that there is only one God, the Father, and one Lord, Jesus Christ (the Son of God).

@joshuab Fully agree. Don’t forget the Spirit!

Don, are you a Unitarian?

@joshuab no. Maybe I wasn’t clear in my responses. I believe in the trinity, including Jesus’ divinity. My point was, he did not claim divinity in this passage. I can see why it’s tempting to read that into the conversation (because He is devine), but I’m arguing it’s not there. Instead, Jesus is taking the opportunity to explain that goodness cannot be attained through works, but by following Him. More clear? Less clear? If you do see He’s making that claim, can you explain how you read that in context?

Don, I believe that Jesus is the divine Son of God, but I do not believe that Jesus is God, which contradicts all of the Scriptures.
